# Removing unknown character of displayed string

Tags: c#, string, sockets, vb6

I have a program whereby program TCPConnector in vb6 , program B in c# . Both communicate using Sockets.Both in strings format.

As you can see , I've inputted several strings inside,"**IN1UOXF"** and also **"blablabla"** in TCPConnector program . However , when received in program B ,suddenly "[]" appears in all the response i'm getting .

I've tried using Trim() , but that does not work .

Anyone can suggest a good way to overcome this?

[image: unknown_char]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a newline problem (like: \r\n)
Set a breakpoint and look at the string in HEX, then you will see what char is the problem.

Comment: the things is, every strings/integer I key in will result the same thing .
i'm not sure I understand how to accomplish what you suggest "look at the string in HEX" .

Comment: I thought of something like:  string test =  "hans";
byte[] testByte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(test);